# Cómo puedo hacer esta sentencia SQL sin utilizar el IN y obtener los mismos resultados?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta sentencia:

```
  SELECT riesgo 
  FROM CI_Riesgo 
  WHERE proceso LIKE '21.2 Seguridad Institucional en Oficinas Centrales'
  AND riesgo NOT IN (SELECT nomRiesgo FROM CI_Riesgo_T WHERE  estadoRiesgo LIKE 'En%' OR estadoRiesgo LIKE '%Asignado%')
```

Pero la herramienta donde la voy a ejecutar no contiene la expresión IN (no pregunten por qué) por lo que no puedo ejecutar dicha sentencia.

Así que busco la manera de hacer una sentencia diferente con los mismos resultados. ¿Hay alguna forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa (que no sé si tu herramienta soporta), sería usar `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT riesgo 
FROM CI_Riesgo r
WHERE proceso LIKE '21.2 Seguridad Institucional en Oficinas Centrales'
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                FROM CI_Riesgo_T
                WHERE  (estadoRiesgo LIKE 'En%' 
                OR estadoRiesgo LIKE '%Asignado%')
                AND nomRiesgo = r.riesgo)
;
```

Como comentario, la forma en que estás usando `LIKE` en la primera condición del `WHERE` es lo mismo que simplemente usar `=`, ya que no tiene wildcards.

Si por algún motivo desconocido no puedes usar `NOT EXISTS`, entonces podrías usar un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT r.riesgo 
FROM CI_Riesgo r
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT nomRiesgo
            FROM CI_Riesgo_T
            WHERE estadoRiesgo LIKE 'En%' 
            OR estadoRiesgo LIKE '%Asignado%') rt
    ON r.riesgo = rt.nomRiesgo
WHERE r.proceso LIKE '21.2 Seguridad Institucional en Oficinas Centrales'
AND rt.nomRiesgo IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Desgraciadamente tampoco. Lo que pasa es que en dicha herramienta se va construyendo el SQL en base a información que te muestra. En cuanto a operadores los únicos que te permite usar son: AND, OR, AND NOT, OR NO, <>, <, >, <=, >=, LIKE, IS, IS NOT y todos los JOINS.

Comment: Excelente. Con LEFT JOIN queda perfecto. Muchas gracias.